# Fill an Id list with no Id ? (trailhead Trigger)

Tags: trigger, id, key

I'm facing an issue understanding a trigger provided by Trailhead (link here),

There is a List  of Ids declared and filled in a loop, and in that loop only a custom object is taken back (not its Id !) ;

I thought 'well, it's not really accurate, let's add the .id' (of course, the custom object does have an .id attribute) ;

But when modifying the code as told, I got an error !

Can you explain me why ?
Is my logical point of view false ?

Thanks for your help,
Alexis

Nb : here is the entier trigger

```
trigger RejectDoubleBooking on Session_Speaker__c (before insert, before update) {
    //collect ID's to reduce data calls
    List<Id> speakerIds = new List<Id>();
    Map<Id,DateTime> requested_bookings = new Map<Id,DateTime>();

    //get all speakers related to the trigger
    //set booking map with ids to fill later
    for(Session_Speaker__c newItem : trigger.new) {
        requested_bookings.put(newItem.Session__c,null);
        speakerIds.add(newItem.Speaker__c);
    }
    //fill out the start date/time for the related sessions
    List<Session__c> related_sessions = [SELECT ID, Session_Date__c from Session__c WHERE ID IN :requested_bookings.keySet()];
    for(Session__c related_session : related_sessions) {
        requested_bookings.put(related_session.Id,related_session.Session_Date__c);
    }
    //get related speaker sessions to check against
    List<Session_Speaker__c> related_speakers = [SELECT ID, Speaker__c, Session__c, Session__r.Session_Date__c from Session_Speaker__c WHERE Speaker__c IN :speakerIds];
    //check one list against the other
    for(Session_Speaker__c requested_session_speaker : trigger.new) {
        DateTime booking_time = requested_bookings.get(requested_session_speaker.Session__c);
        for(Session_Speaker__c related_speaker : related_speakers) {
            if(related_speaker.Speaker__c == requested_session_speaker.Speaker__c &&
               related_speaker.Session__r.Session_Date__c == booking_time) {
                   requested_session_speaker.addError('The speaker is already booked at that time');
               }
        }
    }
}
```

And my specific logical issue is there :

[image]

---

Thanks Santanu,

It's more master-detailed relationship (*) ;

> In the below line, newItem.Session__c is actually referring to the object based on the Id

```
requested_bookings.put(newItem.Session__c,null);
```

I do not understand how it's a reference to an Id ?

I'm not really at ease with the way SOQL works with relationship queries,
I think I've a problem visualising how SOQL works, to travel foreign key relationship ...

In the second part of your answer, you said :

> Now, if you need to use .Id then you have use relationship just like as follows

```
requested_bookings.put(newItem.Session__r.Id,null);
```

I see here, you're requesting the __R --> relation,
Does the trigger work the same way if I do this ?

How can I learn about manipulating the relations, then ?

Thanks again

(*) :
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding you have lookup fields like `Session__c` and `Speaker__c` in the `Session_Speaker__c` object.

In the below line, `newItem.Session__c` is actually referring to the object based on the Id.

```
requested_bookings.put(newItem.Session__c,null);
```

Now, if you need to use `.Id` then you have use relationship just like as follows

```
requested_bookings.put(newItem.Session__r.Id,null);
```

**Update based on your answer**

If you try to fetch only the recordId from SOQL just use

```
SELECT Session__c FROM Session_Speaker__c WHERE ...
```

If you try to fetch other attributes like Name etc then use

```
SELECT Session__r.Name FROM Session_Speaker__c WHERE ...
```

Here Id is implicit and no need to use explicitly as `Session__r.Id` rather use the field api name as `Session__c`.